# SQL Server memory usage

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to understand more about the memory usage for [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server). I can't seem to figure out what's exactly stored in the memory buffer. My setup is a [Windows Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008) x64, 8 GB RAM, [SQL Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2008) standard R2, maximum SQL Server memory 6000 MB.

After running SQL Server a couple of hours, the resource monitor shows `sqlservr.exe` has used about 6000 MB of memory, but when I check the usage for data and plan caches I get less than 6000 MB:

```
Cached plans          2541 MB
Database data cached  2706 MB
Total                 5247 MB
```

I used `sys.dm_exec_cached_plan` and `sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors` to find these values, so from these values I don't know what the 750 MB are used for... I don't think SQL Server is reserving memory since this is a x64 machine... Am I missing something here?

Comment: Code? Data other than DB data? Nothing at all?

Comment: @AndrewBarber No code needed.  The OP provided plenty of information.

Comment: @Shark I wasn't asking for code; I was offering random suggestions for possible answers. :p

Comment: @Shark I think Andrew was giving suggestions for what is occupying the remaining memory, i.e. executing code

Comment: @AndrewBarber My apologies!!!!  I completely misunderstood your comment. :)

Comment: @Shark That's what I get for being snarky! (Sharky?)

Comment: @AndrewBarber Hahaha Very clever.

Answer (score 4):

There are other memory consumers outside of the buffer pool.  For instance, SQL Server will use memory for worker threads, multi-page allocations, linked servers, extended stored procedures, CLR, etc.

The buffer pool is never going to equate to 100% of memory consumed by SQL Server.  It's a common misconception, as well as setting max memory will be the actual max memory SQL Server uses (not true).

**EDIT**:  Here's how I think you could get non-buffer pool memory size.  *Note: wait for the input of other SQL Server professionals before taking this query as fact.  I cannot guarantee that it is absolutely correct.*

```
declare 
    @data_cache_size_mb decimal(12, 2),
    @plan_cache_size_mb decimal(12, 2),
    @total_mem_mb decimal(12, 2)

select
    @data_cache_size_mb = count(*) * 8 / 1024.
from sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors

select
    @plan_cache_size_mb = sum(size_in_bytes) / 1024. / 1024.
from sys.dm_exec_cached_plans

select
    @total_mem_mb = sum(pages_allocated_count) * 8 / 1024.
from sys.dm_os_memory_objects

select
    @data_cache_size_mb as data_cache_size_mb,
    @plan_cache_size_mb as plan_cache_size_mb,
    @data_cache_size_mb + @plan_cache_size_mb as buffer_pool_size_mb,
    @total_mem_mb as total_instance_mem_mb,
    @total_mem_mb - (@data_cache_size_mb + @plan_cache_size_mb) as non_buffer_pool_size_mb
```

Comment: is there a way to check the memory usage for those components? or a way to calculate?

Comment: @kenux See my edit.  I'll rehash this, I am not completely sure that my theory is absolutely accurate.  I'd wait for other knowledgeabe professionals to chime in with their opinions before taking my query as 100% correct/factual.

Comment: Note that in SQL Server 2012 the max server memory setting is much more reliable because the memory manager *can* now control CLR, multi-page, etc.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I didn't know that.  That's a bit of a disadvantage, though, because it's nice to be able to control the buffer pool size.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Does my theory look correct in my query??  I'm just spitballing and trying to drill down into OP's question.

Comment: mmm for the buffer pool size i get about the same I got before 5230 MB and total instance mem is 3308 MB... the non buffer pool is a negative number -1922 MB... i think i need to tweak the arithmetic for the instance memory, i think this should be about 6000 MB right? also should i poke around in the sys.dm_os_memory_objects DMV to look for non-buffer object details?